# Should I create a shooting animation with the bullet in blender or in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, blender

I have been working on a new asset for my new sci-fi game using blender and later importing it into unity. A thought has struck my mind quiet often about the animation. Should I create both the shooting pose or action with the bullet together in blender, or should I just create the pose in blender and create the bullet in Unity? To put the question in simpler terms, where do I create the bullet's movement upon shooting for a basic looking gun? Should I make it like a projectile ball, or should I make it like a small object moving forward with high velocity?

Comment: Do the bullets do anything? Presumably they do. If they do, they need to exist in Unity. Ergo...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want your bullet to be an object then you would need to model it in Blender and bring it into Unity and then turn it into a Prefab and give it whatever custom components you want. As far as your shooting mechanic would work is up to you but, the most basic implementation would be to call a `Shoot()` method you create where you would then Instantiate your bullet prefab and give it a position, rotation, and presumably a velocity.

Some people forgo a model entirely and just perform a ray cast out of the end of the weapon and check if it hits something. How your shooting mechanic works is entirely up to you.